# Don't know how to calculate multivariate minima and maxima for my partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been asked to search for local extreme values for this function:

```
f(p, q) = p^2 − 2pq + q^2 + 2p − 2q + 3
```

I have calculated the partial derivatives as:

Partial Derivative with respect to p:

```
∂f/∂p = 2p - 2q + 2
```

Partial Derivative with respect to q:

```
∂f/∂q = -2p + 2q - 2
```

Then I am searching for the partial derivative = 0 to find the local extreme value. This is where I run into trouble.

First I set the partial derivative with respect to p to zero:

```
2p - 2q + 2 = 0
2p = 2q - 2
p = q - 1
```

Then I set the partial derivative with respect to q to zero:

```
-2p + 2q - 2 = 0
```

Then I substitute the p in terms of q:

```
-2(q - 1) + 2q - 2 = 0
-2q + 2 + 2q -2 = 0
```

Then the -2q and + 2q cancel each other out:

```
-2q + 2q - 2 - 2 = 0
```

I also tried it the other way around:

```
2p - 2q + 2 = 0
-2q = -2p - 2
q = p + 1

-2p + 2(p + 1) - 2 = 0
-2p + 2p + 2 - 2 = 0
0 = 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation setting the partial derivative with respect to $p$ to zero is indeed $$p = q-1$$
The equation setting the partial derivative with respect to $q$ to zero is also $$p = q-1$$
Generally, these would be two distinct equations and you could solve the pair for $(p,q)$ but here there is a line of local almost-saddle-point minima all at $p = q-1$.

You could see this from the function:
$$
f(p,q) = (p-q+1)^2 + 2
$$
which will attain its minimum value $(2)$ along the line $p = q-1$.

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic part $p^2 - 2pq + q^2$ is a square, so you don't get isolated critical points, you get an entire line of minima.
$$ p^2 - 2pq + q^2 + 2p-2q + 3 = (p-q)^2 + 2 (p-q)+3 = (p-q+1)^2 + 2 $$
Anywhere on the line $p-q+1=0$ the value is $2,$ and that is the minimum. On any other line such as $p-q + 7 = 0,$ the function is again some (larger) constant

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Substitution will be a simpler way for this function. Rewrite it a
$$f(p,q)=(p-q)^2+2(p-q)+3=(p-q+1)^2+2,$$
so, setting $t=p-q+1$, you only have to determine the extrema of the single-variable function $\varphi(t)=t^2+2$, which shouldn't be too hard.